# Websphere Server 6.0 CreateFailureException while running Web application

Tags: web-applications, ejb, websphere, java1.4

This application is running on WAS 7 but When i run Web application having EJB layer in WAS 6.0, it is throwing me following exception:  `java.rmi.ServerException RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: com.ibm.ejs.container.CreateFailureException nested exception is: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` I made all the necessary changes regarding database, shared library but still getting same error. Is there anything needs to be done for EJB application and rmi in websphere server 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this post](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=48225), it sounds like WebSphere Application 6.0 does not support EJB 3.0, although you may be able to do better with WebSphere 6.1, if that's an option.

Comment: Its EJB 2.1, Java 1.4

Comment: Sounds like your application uses EJB 3.0 features (which work on WAS 7), but aren't valid in EJB 2.1 (so don't work in WAS 6)?